# TemplateUrl not loading in Angular2 unit Testing with karma and Jasmin

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner

templateUrl is not loading in Angular2 unit Testing with karma and Jasmin,
but template is working, I don't want to put html in my component files so I'm using templateUrl.

I found this https://github.com/sjelin/karma-redirect-preprocessor 
and altered the karma.config file but it doesn't seem to be working.

Please let me know if anyone has complete example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using webpack

1.Run `npm install raw-loader --save`

2.Instead of `templateUrl:'./template.html'` use `template: require('raw!./templat.html)`

Comment: im using systemjs and was able to solve it by simply editing the following line in karma conf to make sure html files are included `{ pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: true, watched: true },`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few known issues with testing components that use `templateUrl`

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5662
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5601

Answer (score 1):

I modified the value of appAssets to have a leading slash in karma.config.js.

```
var appAssets = '/base/app/';
...
proxies: {
  "/app/": appAssets
}
```